# c programing logic for reading sensor over UART

Tags: c, logic, uart

I'm trying to read data from a sensor connected to an mcu over UART. When powered the sensor outputs continuously an ASCII capital “R”, followed by four ASCII character digits representing distance in millimeters, followed by a carriage return (ASCII 13).

I was wondering if somebody could help me figure out a logic to get a reading e.g. 9999 as a variable called reading.

Should I use the blocking or non blocking function and how would I isolate the characters if the data is streaming in?

Comment: What do you think you should use?

Comment: Blocking means the function is not going to return until a character arrives. Non-blocking means it will return whether a character is available or not (and it will let you know if there was). Whether you want blocking or non-blocking  depends upon the rest of your logic, so you have to answer that yourself.

Answer (score 0):

First I would go with the blocking version. I suppose you could expect missing chars at the beginning, because the sensor may start streaming chars before you actually read data. So if the UART gets full, well you might need it. So sample code would be:

```
#define CR (13)
uart_t my_uart; // You need to setup this
uart_status_t status;
uint8_t c;
int status;
char distance[255] = { 0 }; // Whatever, large enough
int seen_r = 0; // You have not yet seen 'R' 
int offset = 0;

while ((status = uart_read(my_uart, &c, &status)) == 0)
{
   if (seen_r) 
   {
      if (c == CR)
      {
          printf("Distance: %s\n", distance);
          seen_r = 0;
          memset(distance, 0, sizeof(distance));
      }
      if (offset < sizeof(distance)-1)
      {
          distance[offset++] = (char)c;
      }
      else
      {
          printf("Unexpected size, reset!\n"); 
          seen_r = 0;
          memset(distance, 0, sizeof(distance));
      }
   }
   else
   {
      if (c != 'R') continue;
      seen_r = 1;
   }
}
```

Of course this is untested code, but it may give you some hints.
Basically, you have a state machine which starts with `'R'` and ends with `CR`.

Comment: Suggest `if (offset < sizeof(distance) - 1)` to avoid printing a non-null character terminated array.

Comment: @Aif thanks for your help - quick question - where does `seen_r` get set to 1 - to enter the first if loop? Also is 'next' a keyword in c?